# Tikzpicture and matrix AND a back decoration

Tags: books, tikz-matrix

I want to create a decoration rectangle or triangle to emphasize the zeros of a matrix in a book \documentclass.
This code **works fine in qtikz** and ktikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners]
  \draw[very thin,fill=yellow!50,yellow!50](-0.25,0.75)  rectangle +(1.4,-1.4)--cycle;
  \draw (0,0) node {$\theta =\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}$ };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It shows a yellow rectangle below the matrix (I use a macro to get the correct matrix, but in order to simplify this code, I just put the matrix environment).
But and here is the question: **the yellow rectangle doesn't appear** when I compile this code inside Texstudio o (years ago) Kile. ¿What I'm doing wrong?

My solution was to export a pdf with qtikz, but this obviously is no a solution when wanted to change the size or family of the fonts.

[image: image in qtikz]

Comment: https://imgbox.com/CGG9a53B

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). If I add the necessary packages, it compiles fine and the yellow rectangle is printed. Some comments: Use `\fill[yellow!50]` instead of `\draw[very thin,fill=yellow!50,yellow!50]`, use `\node at (0,0)` instead of `\draw (0,0) node` and there is no need to use `-- cycle` when using `rectangle`.

Comment: You can have a look to the `nicematrix` package that could be helpful in that case.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Beg your pardon for MWe. "\node at" is not work in my case, but "\fill" does, I used "cycle" because there are  other types, just to keep all lines alike. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

$[\theta] = $%
\begin{varwidth}[t]{5cm}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
\Block[fill=yellow!50,rounded-corners]{3-3}{}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
Nula
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

---

Another possibility:

```
$[\theta] = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,last-row]
\Block[fill=yellow!50,rounded-corners]{3-3}{}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\Block[l]{1-3}{\text{Nula}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thank you. But what about a diagonal, or upper matrix? It seems will be ´´stepwise´´

Comment: Runaway argument?
corners]{3-3}{} 0 \unskip \__nicematrix_end_Cell: \relax $\do@row@strut \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \__nicematrix_Block_i.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 0 &
         0 & 0 \\

Comment: @JOM: Your LaTeX is probably not up-to-date...